# Maximize sharpe ratio. Is $x_0 x_1 \ge x_2$ convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, finance, non-convex-optimization

I'm dealing with the portfolio optimization case study of mosek and want to add limits on the total number of assets to be re-weighted and the turnover of each asset.

The objective is to maximize Sharpe ratio $\frac{\mu^{T}w}{\sqrt{w^T \Sigma w}}$ or to minimize $\frac{\sqrt{w^T \Sigma w}}{\mu^{T}w}$ with $\mu^T w \ge 0$ and budget constraint $e^Tw=1$. It's similar to linear fractional problem, so I introduce a variable $g$ to get rid of the denominator.
$$
\min_{\hat{w}} \sqrt{\hat{w}^T \Sigma \hat{w}}
$$
where $\hat{w}$ is the scaled portfolio weights that $\hat{w} = w * g$. By cholesky decomposition we can have $GG^T = \Sigma$ and $\sqrt{\hat{w}^T \Sigma \hat{w}}=\sqrt{\hat{w}^TGG^T\hat{w}}=||G^T\hat{w}||_2$ which can be expressed by a quadratic cone $(s, t) \in Q^{n+1}$ and $t = G^T\hat{w}$

$$
e^{T}\hat{w} = g
$$

$$
\mu^{T}\hat{w} = 1
$$

$$
\hat{w}_{i} - \hat{w}_{0_{i}}  \le \hat{z}_{i}
$$
$$
\hat{w}_{0_{i}} - \hat{w}_{i}  \le \hat{z}_{i} \quad (\hat{z}_{i}=|\hat{w}_i - \hat{w}_{0_i}|)
$$
$$
\hat{z}_{i}  \le g * U_{i}y_{i}
$$
$$
e^{T}y \le k
$$
$$
-\hat{w}_{i}    \le 0
$$
$$ 
-g       \le 0
$$

$$ 
 y\in \{0, 1\} , y \in Z
$$

$U_{i}$ is given as a limit on each asset. $z_i$ is the turnover of each asset, and $g$ is the re-scale factor. $y_{i}$ works as an indicator to limit the number of assets to be re-weighted.

So here we have $z_i \leq g * y_{i}$, while $g, y_{i}, z_{i} \geq 0$. I'm not sure whether it's convex or not. If so, how to deal with this inequality.

I tried to add another variable $c$ that $c_i^2 = z_i$ so we can have a rotated quadratic cone $g * y_i \ge c_i^2$. But I don't know how to link $c$ with $z$ either.

Comment: You can just do $z_i\leq M_iy_i$ for some suitably adapted constant $M_i$. There is no need to have the $g$ in there, if you just want to count how many $z_i$ are nonzero this linear constraint will do the same job of turning $y_i$ into an indicator.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks, Michal. But I'm still confused about the $g$ and I make my question clear.  Since $w$ has been scaled and marked as $\hat{w}=w * g$, I think $z$ should also be scaled as $\hat{z}=z * g$ . So if I want the original $z_i$ not to exceed $U_i=10%$, here I have to constrain $\hat{z}$ within [0, 0.1 * g]. And $g$ is also a variable. It could be 5 in one scenario and 80 in another.  But if I don't want to limit the turnover of each asset, I think the original $z_{i} <= 1 * y_{i}$ can be expressed as $\hat{z} <= g_{max} * y_{i}$ where $g_{max}$ is the suitably adapted constant

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek So I'm not sure is it still unsolvable as a convex problem?  Or could you please provide some other suggestions about this problem? Maybe some new methods to represent the turnover part $z$ instead of two linear ones or some new methods to count how many $z_{i}$ are nonzero? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Mosek 10 you can also write ($z_i >0 \implies y_i=1$) without introducing an explicit big M yourself and hope the solver will find a good one for you or branch on this condition. Look for Disjunctive Constraints in your manual https://www.mosek.com/products/version-10/. But that's just sort of a syntactic sugar, I don't think there is any other essentially different/better way to model what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks a lot!